# Extracting specific nodes from XML using XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I was trying to extract a particular set of nodes from the following XML structure using XML::Twig, but have been stuck ever since. I need to extract the 'player' nodes from the following structure and do a string match/replace on each of these node values.

```
<pep:record>
    <agency type="player">
        <subrecord type="scout">
            <isnum>123XXX (print)</isnum>
            <isnum>234YYY (mag)</isnum>
        </subrecord>
        <subrecord type="group">
        </subrecord>
    </agency>
</record>
```

I tried using the following code, but I get pointed to a hash reference rather than actual string.

```
my $parser = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {
        isnum => sub { print $_->text."::" },
    });

foreach my $rec (split(/::/, $parser->parse($my_xml))) {
    if ($rec =~ m/print/) {
        ($print = $rec)  =~ s/( \(print\))//;
    }
    elsif($rec =~ m/mag/) {
        ($mag = $rec) =~ s/( \(mag\))//;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example XML is not complete. There's no reference to either `player` or `::` in it.

Comment: Oops! My bad! mis-spelt a variable.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I was talking about the XML. There's a `>` missing at the end, but also you are referring to the `player` nodes, but there are no such nodes in your XML. We need a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need something like this:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use XML::Twig;

my $my_xml = <<EOL;
<pep:record>
    <agency type="player">
        <subrecord type="scout">
            <isnum>123XXX (print)</isnum>
            <isnum>234YYY (mag)</isnum>
        </subrecord>
        <subrecord type="group">
        </subrecord>
    </agency>
</pep:record>
EOL

my @records;

my $parser = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {
        isnum => sub { push @records, $_->text },
    });

$parser->parse($my_xml);

foreach my $rec (@records) {
    if ($rec =~ m/print/) {
        $rec  =~ s/( \(print\))//;
    }
    elsif ($rec =~ m/mag/) {
        $rec =~ s/( \(mag\))//;
    }

    say $rec;
}
```